# Create ESLint rule for TS files only

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, custom-eslint-plugin

I'm writing a custom plugin that based on various conditions, it fixes an error by passing a new type. for example,

before the fix:

```js
const x = X("A");
          ~ <-- Error
```

after the fix:

```js
const x = X<A>("A");
```

Everything seems to working, except the part where the following rule is being enforced in JS files as well. How can I enforce the rule to run only in TS files?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achive this, is to use "overrides" in your .eslintrc.js file. to only enable it on .ts files and keep the rest of your eslint config the same:
You can look at this in more detail on https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns

Example:

```
module.exports = {
...
   "overrides": [
       "files": [
           "**/*.ts"
       ],
       "rules": {
           "your-cool-rule": "error"
       }
   ]
...
}
```